# Is there a PPA or Snap for Anki?

Tags: snap, anki

The Ubuntu vision of packaging apps in a way that automatically gets at least security updates still seems very important.
So as I install [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) I again resist the advice to install it manually, directly downloading the latest from their web page.

Instead I want to see a snap package or a PPA which someone will keep up-to-date, but I can't find either.

There is an Anki package in Ubuntu Bionic, Version 2.1.0beta36, but I note that  running it says

> "This is an BETA build - please do not package it up for Linux distributions".

Am I missing anything, or are there plans to keep the Ubuntu package updated for at least security issues?

Note: I've also reported this to Anki: [Packaged version for automatically getting updates: Snap? Ubuntu PPA? / Anki (Computer Version) / Discussion Area - Anki Support](https://anki.tenderapp.com/discussions/ankidesktop/30679-packaged-version-for-automatically-getting-updates-snap-ubuntu-ppa?unresolve=true)

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find any PPA with anki either. And the solution to install system wide with
the command:

> sudo make install

is not the right way. I agree.

Luckly Anki doesn't need to be installed system wide to work. You can install it locally to your user.

This is what I did:

1. Install and then uninstall the Ubuntu anki package to install all dependencies.

   > apt install anki
   >
   > apt purge anki
2. Download from [Anki website](https://apps.ankiweb.net/downloads/current/anki-2.1.8-linux-amd64.tar.bz2)
3. Extract to your home folder

   > tar xjf Downloads/anki-2.1.8-amd64.tar.bz2
4. Add the extracted bin directory to your PATH

   > export PATH=$PATH:~/anki-2.1.8-linux-amd64/bin

Comment: Thank you, it's helpful to know that can work. But this approach requires every user to constantly be alert for security bugs. So an updated package or snap would not just save us all lots of time, but also keep us all safer.

Answer (score 1):

you can install anki from this unofficial snap: https://snapcraft.io/anki-woodrow

install command

```
snap install anki-woodrow
```

atm it has the latest version (2.1.15).